# How to display image/Video thumbnail in android

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

Hi all I want to display image/video thumbnail in my application .I have used following code for retrieve the thumbnails and list them in the adapter.
Following is the code

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        private final String[] VideoValues;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] VideoValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.VideoValues = VideoValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.out.println("***********In getView************");
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from gridlayout.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlayout, null);

                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
                textView.setText(fileList[position]);
                System.out.println("value of fileList[position]" + fileList[0]);
                // set image
                ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

                Bitmap bmThumbnail;

                System.out
                        .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> file path>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                                + fileList[position]);

                bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FILE_PATH
                        + fileList[position],
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                if (bmThumbnail != null) {
                    System.out
                            .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                    imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>NO THUMB NAIL>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

                }

            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // return 0;
            return VideoValues.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Its working fine for image and videos in Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 ,But its not working in acer iconia   A501.any thoughts on this.

Both are running HoneyComb.

Rgds,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9461283/1012284

Comment: @Deva cool its ok. out of 4 questions he got only 2 answers. he is 73%  better than you.

Comment: That was just a suggestion. No offence but 73% is still better than 69% .

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps for you. Just tweak it to your application:

```
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        String filePath = fileList.get(position).getFilePath();
        String dateTaken = fileList.get(position).getDateTaken();
        Long type = fileList.get(position).getType();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if(type == MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        else if(type == MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 0);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        textView.setText(dateTaken);
```